# Install mysql-server 5.7 on lv mounted on /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, ansible

Since 2 weeks, I'm working on MySQL deployment and stuff with Ansible. I have to install MySQL on a LV.

Before MySQL deployment, Ansible script creates `/var/lib/mysql`, LV and mount it on `/var/lib/mysql`. Then, it create MySQL user and MySQL group to set 0700 right on MySQL directory. When it done, Ansible deploy MySQL 5.7.

Part of my Ansible code :

```
- name: "Group : mysql"
  group:
    name: "mysql"
    state: "present"
  tags:
    - User mysql

- name: "user : mysql"
  user:
    name: "mysql"
    shell: "mysql"
    group: "mysql"
    createhome: "no"
    append: "True"
    state: "present"
  tags:
    - User

- name: "Set rights on mysql dir "
  file:
    path: "/var/lib/mysql"
    owner: "mysql"
    group: "mysql"
    mode: 0700
  tags:
    - mysql dir rights

- name: "mysql root password"
  debconf:
    name: "mysql-server"
    question: "mysql-server/root_password"
    value: "{{ password_root_mysql }}"
    vtype: "password"
  when: password_root_mysql is defined
  tags:
    - Install  

- name: "mysql root password confirmation"
  debconf:
    name: "mysql-server"
    question: "mysql-server/root_password_again"
    value: "{{ password_root_mysql }}"
    vtype: "password"
  when: password_root_mysql is defined
  tags:
    - Install mysql

- name: "Install : MySQL Server"
  apt:
    update_cache: "True"
    name: "mysql-server"
    install_recommends: "True"
  tags:
    - Install mysql
  notify:
    - stop mysql   

- name: "Copie du template root.cnf.j2 vers root/.my.cnf "
  template:
    src: "{{ mysql_template_rootcnf }}"
    dest: "~/.my.cnf"
    owner: "root"
    mode: "0600"
  tags:
    - Install mysql
```

So when I try to install `mysql-server` without any LV and directory settings, it works. But when I prepare directory MySQL with good rights, installation doesn't work, whether manual or automatic deployment.

**Any ideas ?**

> Ubuntu 16.04 with MYSQL 5.7. 
>   Ansible v2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the problem, Lost+Found directory in /var/lib/mysql (lv mounted on it) is considerated like a database, mysql doesn't like it. In my code, ive just added :

```
- name: "Remove lost+found from {{ mysql_dir }}"
  file: 
    path: "{{ mysql_dir }}/lost+found"  
    state: absent
```